Python library to extract metadata from video file stored in variable, rather than on filesystem
Is there a standard solution for extracting metadata (like aspect ratio, codec, etc) from video data stored in a Python variable, rather than from a file on disk?
I see people point most often to ffmpeg-python for video metadata analysis, but as far as I can tell, it can only operate on a filename rather than an object in memory. One possible workaround is to tell ffmpeg-python to use stdin pipe as input and then output the contents of the variable to that pipe, but this seems cumbersome. If ffmpeg-python accepted a file handle rather than filename, you could use BytesIO, but this does not appear to be supported either.
To simplify, I have binary video data in variable x. I'd like to be able to do something like:
import ffmpeg
metadata=ffmpeg.FFProbe(x)

But this won't work because x is not a filename, and the FFProbe function also won't accept a handle.
Is there another Python module that would be more suited to the task?

the Python package called "ffmpeg-python" has nothing to do with ffmpeg. it's just one of those amateur packages that call ffmpeg as a subprocess. if you want a proper wrapper, use PyAV. -- ffprobe behavior isn't found in a library, only in the CLI tool. just call ffprobe as a subprocess and tell it to emit JSON.

When you say "video data stored in a Python variable", it seems like you really mean "some format video file file stored in memory" (as a Python variable, probably of type bytes). That would still be a 'file' though, and it's not very likely that tools designed to operate on data in memory would expect the data to be formatted as a file. There are plenty of Python video manipulation libraries that expect the video to be in memory, but typically in a more useful format. Where is this data coming from? What format is it in? Is it just a downloaded file (in any format), for example?

You say using a pipe is 'cumbersome', but why so? The solution is relatively straightforward, although it does require ffmpeg to be installed and its location to be known or on the system path:
import json
import subprocess
import pprint


def ffprobe(video_data):
    p = subprocess.run(
        'ffprobe -i - -print_format json -show_format -v quiet'.split(),
        input=video_data, capture_output=True
    )
    return json.loads(p.stdout)


with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    video_file = f.read()
metadata = ffprobe(video_file)
pprint.pprint(metadata)

This works and makes the data available quickly and in an accessible format. A potential downside is the overhead of starting a separate process, and loading and starting a separate executable.
If performance is key to your solution, you could look at libraries like hachoir, or if the metadata you need is very specific and you only need it for specific formats, there may be libraries specific to that format that would allow you to do the job. In the extreme, you could parse the bytes object yourself.
But it seems unlikely that your need for performance would outweigh the added complexity, lack of support for formats and future changes, and optimised performance of a mature toolset like ffmpeg itself. If the answer to "why are you doing this?" is speed, simplicity, or flexibility, you should probably just use ffmpeg.
If the answer is portability, you could consider distributing some form of ffmpeg with your script or package, assuming licensing allows this.

Thanks, this is helpful. You are correct that the video (an MP4 container with standard codec streams) is in memory as a bytes. My goal is mainly portability and to a lesser extent efficiency.  I’ll look into hachoir (and PyAV, as suggested by another commenter), that looks promising.

PyAV does not run a subprocess, just to make that clear. calling functions in a library, passing memory that doesn't need copying, is vastly different from poking a subprocess to make it emit binary data over a pipe. in the case of ffprobe, that can be excused. it's text output.

hachoir appears to be a library for generic binary data dissection. that library does not know anything about typical video formats. one would have to reimplement sizable portions of ffmpeg. I don't think that library is a suitable recommendation here, unless OP seriously wants to go for "portability" by implementing the dissection without relying on ffmpeg or its libraries.

@ChristophRackwitz apologies, you're correct - ffmpeg loads the ffmpeg libraries, I had misread previously and will update the comment.

As the package states in its readme: "If the ffmpeg command does the job without you bending over backwards, PyAV is likely going to be more of a hindrance than a help." I'm not a fan of hachoir, but I mentioned it because it's a rare example of actually processing the file in memory - which is what you asked for. You probably shouldn't ignore the actualy advice I (and the makes of PyAV) are giving you though. (apologies to @ChristophRackwitz for making his comment appear out of  order)
